# why my string index is out of range?

Tags: java, joptionpane, turtle-graphics

I am making a hangman game for my ap computer science class and could not seem to figure out how to fix my problem with the strings. I am getting an out of bounds index error. it says

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7

occurring here:

```
if(theGuess.equals(wordToGuess.substring(i,i+1)))
```

Here is the program code if it is any help.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
public class Hangman extends BasicGame
{
    private final String WORDCHOICES= "apple"+"great"+"zebra"+"mouse"+"chick"+"class"+"abhor"+"abide"
        +"fuzzy"+"brute"+"blunt"+"comic"+"cater"+"stone"+"chaos"+"dufus"+"earth"+"decal"+"happy"+"heist"
        +"idler"+"lions"+"hates"+"idols"+"lasso"+"lives"+"lisps"+"major"+"mound"+"mango"+"meter"+"mercy"
        +"marry"+"pilot"+"plots"+"pants"+"overt"+"quack"+"paver"+"polls"+"scorn"+"sapid"+"sails"+"rowdy"
        +"seeks"+"leech"+"seats"+"spade"+"shoes"+"slurp";
    private String wordToGuess;
    private java.util.Random randy;

    private int wordNum;
    private int numCorrect=0;
    private String[] correctLetters= new String[]{"","","","",""};
    HangDraw artist= new HangDraw();
    public Hangman()
    {
        super();
        randy= new java.util.Random();
        for(int i = 0; i<5;i++)
            correctLetters[i]=null;
        wordNum=0;
        numCorrect=0;
        artist.setUp();
    }
    public void guess()
    {
        wordNum= 5*randy.nextInt(50);
        numCorrect=0;
        int wrong=0;
        String userGuess="";
        int partsDrawn=0;
        wordToGuess=WORDCHOICES.substring(wordNum,wordNum+5)+" ";
        while(numCorrect<5&& partsDrawn<5)
        {
            userGuess= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a letter, so far you have: "+ correctLetters[0]+
                        correctLetters[1]+correctLetters[2]+correctLetters[3]+correctLetters[4]);

            if(checkLetter(userGuess))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct Guess");
                //print the letter
            }
            else
            {
                //draw the part of the body
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"incorrect");
                partsDrawn++;
                artist.drawParts(partsDrawn);
            }
        }
        if(partsDrawn==5)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "failed to guess, the word is: "+wordToGuess);
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "correct, the word was: "+ wordToGuess);
        }
    }

    private boolean checkLetter(String theGuess)
    {
        boolean matches=false;
        for(int i=0;i<wordToGuess.length();i++)
        {
            if(theGuess.equals(wordToGuess.substring(i,i+1)))
            {
                correctLetters[i]=theGuess;
                matches=true;
                numCorrect++;
            }
        }
        return matches;
    }

}
```

Thank you for any help you provide

Comment: Are you aware that `WORDCHOICES` is the following string: `applegreatzebramousechickclassabhorabidefuzzybrutebluntcomiccaterstonechaosdufusearthdecalhappyheistidlerlionshatesidolslassoliveslispsmajormoundmangometermercymarrypilotplotspantsovertquackpaverpollsscornsapidsailsrowdyseeksleechseatsspadeshoesslurp`? Why not use an array? Then your words wouldn't be restricted to 5 chars.

Comment: I was not supposed to use an array, my teacher wanted 50 5 letter words in a 250 character string, thanks for the advice though

Comment: Seems like everyday someone is here with a different crazy requirement made up by a teacher. If you want to teach string manipulation, then don't use an example that has a much better solution with an array/collection. Obviously it's not your fault, I just really don't understand sometimes.

Comment: Yeah, its because at this point in the class we havent been taught arrays so we were instructed to use a large string, I however did use an array for part of it, because it was the easiest thing to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are out of range obviously. you cannot substring from end of string.

```
for(int i=0;i<wordToGuess.length();i++)
{
    if(theGuess.equals(wordToGuess.substring(i,i+1)))
    {
        correctLetters[i]=theGuess;
        matches=true;
        numCorrect++;
    }
}
```

Fastest way to find out is to debug the app

Comment: endIndex for substring is exclusive, thus it can be equal to wordToGuess.length(), your solution skips the last character.

Comment: ok thanks, i still needed to have the last character checked though so i concatenated a " " to the end of wordToGuess in the earlier section aswell to fix it

Comment: @abysmaldan Concatenating a space is a terrible solution when all you have to do is fix your loop parameters.

Answer (score 3):

According to the java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29), String#substring throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

> if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

On the last iteration of your loop, `i` will equal the `length` of the string, and `i+1` is greater than the length of the string, hence the exception.

So you need to change:

```
for(int i=0;i<=wordToGuess.length();i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=0;i<wordToGuess.length();i++)
            ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is `for(int i=0;i<=wordToGuess.length();i++)`

Lets assume a simple example, `wordToGuess="ABC"`

The loop generates values for i=0 to i<=3.

For i=0 you select the first character, for i=1 the second, for i=2 the third, i=3 makes no sense.

Thus use `for(int i=0;i<wordToGuess.length();i++)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are out-of-bounds in the preceding `for` loop: `for(int i=0;i<=wordToGuess.length();i++)`.  This will loop past the end of the available characters in the string.  Noting that you are using a substring function which uses endpoint notation, the latter endpoint must be within the bounds of the string and so this loop should be specified as `for(int i=0;i<wordToGuess.length();i++)`.  This will ensure that the last iteration does not invoke the `IndexOutOfBoundsError`.

Comment: Corrected, thank you, missed the 'exclusive' marker in the Java docs on the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition in a `for` loop from `i<=wordToGuess.length()`, to `i<wordToGuess.length()`, because now your loop comes to the moment, when `i` becomes the last element, so the `i+1` naturally points "out of bounds".

Answer (score 0):

make following changes

```
for(int i=0;i<wordToGuess.length();i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Core Java is awesome at telling you what is wrong.  You stated `if(theGuess.equals(wordToGuess.substring(i,i+1)))` is throwing the IndexOutOfBoundsException?  That means `wordToGuess` length is less than one character (i.e. the empty string).  Basically you are getting attempting to get a substring of length 1 [i,i+1).

Because you are student and I think it's important to work through these yourself, I'm just going to give you a hint:  Look at the for loop condition.  Also, step through the code with a debugger, or at least put some System.out.println(wordToGuess) statements in to see what the values are.